# Unified way to access arrays with different types

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generic-list

Supposing I have the following classes:

```
class Master {
  int x;
  int y;

  public int X { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }
  public int Y { get { return y; } set { y = value; } }
}

class Sub1:Master {
  int z;

  public int Z { get { return z; } set { z = value; } }
}

class Sub2:Master {
  int w;

  public int W { get { return w; } set { w = value; } }
}
class Sub3:Master {
  int t;

  public int T { get { return t; } set { t = value; } }
}
```

Then I have defined three different arrays, one for each `Sub*` type:

```
List<Sub1> array1;
List<Sub2> array2;
List<Sub3> array3;
```

And finally I need a way to access all instances in a unified way. The idea was to use a new array `List<T>[] array4 = new[] {array1, array2, array3};` and use an `int` as index, so I don't have to write three times the common operations for properties `X` and `Y`.

However, I can't do it in this way because the three arrays have different type. What can I use?

Comment: Did you try List<Master>[] masterList = new List<Master>[]{array1, array2, array3};

Answer (score 1):

They share a base type so you can create a `List<Master>` to hold instances of all three types.

Ultimately, all objects share the same base type `object` so it always possible to have a `List<object>`, but in this case they share a base type higher in the hierarchy so you can use `Master`.

To create a list for all the instances you can do something like this:

```
var all = new List<Master>(array1.Count + array2.Count + array3.Count);

all.AddRange(array1);
all.AddRange(array2);
all.AddRange(array3);
```

First you create a new list and since you already know what the expected capacity should be you use the constructor overload that accepts an `int capacity`. This way the list does not have to be resized when you add the other collections, which leads to more efficient code.

As a side note and I know this is probably only sample code but nonetheless you should name your variables according to what they represent, so naming something like `array*` should be reserved for when they really represent arrays.

Answer (score 0):

List implements the non-generic interfaces `ICollection`, `IEnumerable` and `IList`, so you can create a new array of `IList[] array4 = { array1, array2, array3 };`

Or, while adding elements at your Lists you could add them (also) to another list of type Master, like this

```
List<Sub1> array1 = new List<Sub1>();
List<Sub2> array2 = new List<Sub2>();
List<Sub3> array3 = new List<Sub3>();
List<Master> array4 = new List<Master>();

...

public void AddSub1(Sub1 sub)
{
    array1.Add(sub);
    array4.Add(sub);
}

public void AddSub2(Sub2 sub)
{
    array2.Add(sub);
    array4.Add(sub);
}

public void AddSub3(Sub3 sub)
{
    array3.Add(sub);
    array4.Add(sub);
}
```

This way, you can iterate over all elements of array4:

```
foreach(Master master in array4)
{
   master.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make this work by using the fact that `IEnumerable<T>` is declared as `IEnumerable<out T>`, and that [`Enumerable.ElementAt<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) is optimized for the *runtime* type of the `IEnumerable<T>` implementing `IList<T>`.  That lets you do this:

```
var x = new IEnumerable<Master>[] {array1, array2, array3};
x[0].ElementAt(4);
```

While still getting constant-time access to the individual elements of the lists.  It feels a little clunky, but should still work.

If it fits the work being done, a better option in my opinion would be to create a generic method, and call the generic method on each of your lists:

```
private void MainMethod()
{
    List<Sub1> array1 = new List<Sub1>();
    List<Sub2> array2 = new List<Sub2>();
    List<Sub3> array3 = new List<Sub3>();
    DoOperation(array1);
    DoOperation(array2);
    DoOperation(array3);
}

private void DoOperation<T>(List<T> list) where T: Master
{
    // do work here
    list[0].X = 0;
}
```